# Celery Eventlet OSError: Load averages are unobtainable

Tags: django, django-celery, eventlet

Our django celery server is running with concurrency value of 500 with eventlet as execution pool. Recently,  we encountered this issue and restarting the server fixed it. I am attaching the traceback of the error.

**python package versions:**
Django 4.1.7
celery 5.2.3
eventlet 0.33.3

I checked the soft and hard limits of the open files if these are of any use.

**soft limits:**

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 31071
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 65536
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 2048
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 31071
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

**hard limits:**

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 31071
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 65536
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 16384
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) unlimited
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 31071
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

I have been using eventlet for the past 6 or 7 months and this is the first time we have faced this issue. how do we prevent this from happening again

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/ubuntu/project_data/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/hub.py", line 476, in fire_timers
  timer()
 File "/home/ubuntu/project_data/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/timer.py", line 59, in __call__
  cb(*args, **kw)
 File "/home/ubuntu/project_data/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eventlet/greenthread.py", line 224, in main
  self._resolve_links()
 File "/home/ubuntu/project_data/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eventlet/greenthread.py", line 240, in _resolve_links
  f(self, *ca, **ckw)
 File "/home/ubuntu/project_data/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/concurrency/eventlet.py", line 62, in _entry_exit
  g.wait()
 File "/home/ubuntu/project_data/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eventlet/greenthread.py", line 181, in wait
  return self._exit_event.wait()
 File "/home/ubuntu/project_data/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eventlet/event.py", line 132, in wait
  current.throw(*self._exc)
 File "/home/ubuntu/project_data/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eventlet/greenthread.py", line 221, in main
  result = function(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/home/ubuntu/project_data/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/asynchronous/timer.py", line 70, in __call__
  return self.fun(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
 File "/home/ubuntu/project_data/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/asynchronous/timer.py", line 137, in _reschedules
  return fun(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/home/ubuntu/project_data/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/worker/heartbeat.py", line 45, in _send
  loadavg=load_average(),
 File "/home/ubuntu/project_data/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/utils/sysinfo.py", line 23, in load_average
  return _load_average()
 File "/home/ubuntu/project_data/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/utils/sysinfo.py", line 13, in _load_average
  return tuple(ceil(l * 1e2) / 1e2 for l in os.getloadavg())
OSError: Load averages are unobtainable
```

Answer (score 0):

The os.getloadavg() method returns the load average over the last 1, 5, and 15 minutes.

This indicates the number of processes in the system run queue (over the last 1, 5, and 15 minutes).

try this :`load1, load5, load15 = os.getloadavg()`